# Are the units incorrect for Storage Read / Write graphs in AWS ECS Container Insights?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

In AWS Console > CloudWatch > Container Insights > Performance monitoring > ECS Tasks, the graphs for both `Storage Read` and `Storage Write` have units shown as `Bytes/Second` like this:

> ###### Storage Read
>
> Bytes/Second

However in both cases the graphs appear to be always monotonically increasing, except for vertical drops on container restart, and have long horizontal sections when I would not expect to be seeing sustained constant IO.

Are these graphs actually showing cumulative `Bytes` rather than the stated `Bytes/Second`?

Looking in the table on [AWS docs for ECS Container Insights metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-metrics-ECS.html) I see `StorageReadBytes` and `StorageWriteBytes` with both say `Unit: Bytes` so, assuming this is referring to the same metrics displayed in the console UI graphs, perhaps this confirms my suspicion that this is a bug in the AWS console UI?

I have attempted to report this using the 'Feedback' button in AWS but posting here in case anyone can confirm or if it helps others who may be worried by a seemingly high rate of sustained I/O.

Comment: I just ran into the same and found your question here. The CloudWatch metric shows bytes/sec but clearly my application is not writing 20GB/sec (for example).. it seems to be a sum.

Comment: This still seems to be an an issue. According to Storage Write on container insight one of our tasks are now writing at >100 GB/sec - and increasing!

Comment: It's 2024 and this is still an issue.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it seems the units are incorrect. I also ran into same observation while debugging an application restart.
It took a while. For me the value was 215 mb/s for StorageReadBytes - when the application was idle.
I think this needs to be raised to AWS team.